# C# while loop not working with server side controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 5 records in my Database and the below code is working fine to retrieve all the 5 records and write them.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
     String a1 = dr[0].ToString();
     Response.Write(a1);
}
```

but, when I remove `Resonse.Write(a1);` and using `repvals = a1;` the output is displaying only last one record but not all records.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    String a1 = dr[0].ToString();
    repvals = a1;
}
```

In the above code repvals is a server side HTML control declared <%=repvals%> and declared as `protected string repvals` in code page.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to concatenate the new string in repvals in each itiration, So Try this instead

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    String a1 = dr[0].ToString();
    repvals += a1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

because you're overwriting the value every time.  You need to concatenate the string, rather than assign it to the same variable every time.  See below:

```
repvals="";
while (dr.Read())
  {
     String a1 = dr[0].ToString();
     repvals = repvals + a1;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared repvals and written a value to it 5 times -- last write is what you see because you're rendering after the loop.  I would use an array or list in your markup and accumulate the values from the db in your loop.